# Arduino control with serial input more then 1 character

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I have the script below and it works.
But I want to control it with a word like `on` or `off` instead of one character.
I tried and searched a lot but without success.

```cpp
/*
Simple LED sketch
*/

int led = 13; // Pin 13

void setup()
{
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT); // Set pin 13 as digital out

    // Start up serial connection
    Serial.begin(115200); // baud rate
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available()) {

        int ser = Serial.read(); //read serial as ascii integer

        if (ser == 'a') { //is this serial byte the ASCII equivalent of 0 through 9?
            digitalWrite(led, HIGH); // on
            Serial.println("aan");
        }
        else if (ser == 'u') {
            digitalWrite(led, LOW); // off
            Serial.println("uit");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any use-case that requires it and justify the increase in payload size and complexity?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Serial.readStringUntil(terminator)`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadStringUntil) to read a string from the serial.

The sent string needs to be terminated with a newline character.
Chose `Newline` in the Arduino IDE's Serial Monitor.

```cpp
String cmd = "";

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available()) {
        cmd = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');

        if (cmd == "on") {
            digitalWrite(led, HIGH); // on
            Serial.println("aan");
        }
        else if (cmd == "off") {
            digitalWrite(led, LOW); // off
            Serial.println("uit");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, this code does not work if(Serial.available()) is not a condition

Comment: @IamtheLawTheLaw what do you mean? I think this code should execute the blocking function only if there is at least one char inside the buffer (I think it is the best you can do without duplicating the buffer). One thing worth noting is that usually on windows the default is to send the new line char as "\r\n", which does not make this code work (you should filter out the \r chars before comparing)

Comment: @IamtheLawTheLaw Just so you know, I ran this code and it works fine.

Comment: Ehm...Ok, cool, happy you happy everyone, I still thing if(Serial.available()) is not a condition. Why? Because you are not really making a condition, Serial.available() usually expects and int. What sequence of characters is inputted in my serial? A string is a series of characters, so if you want Serial.available to actually see what you are inputting with a specific amount such as 0 being the first character (this is because a String is an array of characters) then you have to define it otherwise you just waste memory. But all good, just don't down it because you don't like it. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you are using a char you need to declare a string so you can compare that string to the input, the guy above gave a ok/very slacky/too complex for you answer (sorry no offense I am just trying to show contrast between a complex and a easy answer not trying to offend you) and partially is because he did not explain what he is doing and because he is doing unnecessary/useless work. There is a function in c++ called Serial.readString(), much easier then the stuff up there. Assuming your level of programming (no offense) from your question here is a quick review on data types:

**String = ""**

**int = integer number {1,2,3,4,5,6,...}**

**char = '' <- Notice the difference from String = ""**

**float = floating point number {1.2,4.5,...}**

(These are not all of them, there is more like byte and so on but just make sure you know how to use the above first)

```
    /*
    Simple LED sketch
    */

    int led = 7; // Pin 13
    String ser;  //Declare the string that is going to store what your are going to

//write in the serial

    void setup(){

        // Start up serial connection
        //It's good convention to start the serial before pinMode or any other thing         
//in setup

        Serial.begin(9600); //I don't know why you need such an high baud rate in        

//your thing, 9600 for what you have to do is more than fine, this is just at 
  //what speed the serial is read (in a very general explanation)

        pinMode(led, OUTPUT); // Set pin 13 as digital out

    //make sure you put in here wheter you want to start the led "on" or "off"

    //Eg you want it to start on, then digitalWrite(led, HIGH);


    }

    void loop(){

      ser = Serial.readString();


         if(Serial.available() == 0) {  //You can also use a while loop if you want to
    //This is telling the arduino: if there is something in the serial, then do...

          if(ser == "on"){

                Serial.println("on");
            digitalWrite(led, HIGH);

          }else if(ser == "off"){

            Serial.println("off");
            digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        }
        }

    }
```

Hope it helped!
Also notice how the above code with

```
if(Serial.available())
```

This is a quite WEIRD and SHADY statement and might not work. That's because you are not really telling the int value into the function Serial.available

As the arduino guidelines specify:

```
int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data

void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop() {

        // send data only when you receive data:
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
                // read the incoming byte:
                incomingByte = Serial.read();

                // say what you got:
                Serial.print("I received: ");
                Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
        }
}
```

viewable [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read)

Comment: Let me guess, the guy above gave thumbs down because I bashed his answer, lol

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer because you bashed mine, I downvoted it because yours is wrong.

Comment: [`Serial.readString()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadString) is based on timeout, which is by default 1 sec. That means `readString` blocks for at least 1 sec every time it's called. This also means, the commands will have 1 sec of delay and that you can't send individual commands faster than one per second or you will get multiple commands in a single string. Timeout can be shortened with the [`Serial.setTimeout(milliseconds)`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/SetTimeout) function, but this is still not ideal.

Comment: There is nothing weird and shady with `if(Serial.available())`. Zero gets evaluated as `false` and any other values as `true`. The statement is practically the same as `if(Serial.available() != 0)`. What is weird and shady is your use of it and your comment stating the opposite of what you are actually doing with it. You are waiting to read from the serial buffer without checking, if there is anything in it with `Serial.available()` and then you are checking, if the buffer is empty. Why???

Comment: You also have for no reason, some explanations on data types. And your code is very poorly formatted and hard to read. Too much of your text is dedicated to bashing my answer saying it's too complex and doing unnecessary work, without explaining how is your better. If you just showed a solution using `readString` and explained the problems associated with it, your answer would be good.

Comment: Please give me some references to what you claim, I gave you some look at the link at the bottom, I don't know where you get this stuff, but it would be good to know. As explained above 0 does not get evaluated as false, it's evaluated as the 0 element in an array. A string is an array of characters, thus if you put 1 the element 1 is taken in consideration. Please run the code and see it for your self, I tested it and gave you references. No please give me some references to your claim, and please don't give a link to something like the "DIY guy playing with arduino", something a bit more leg

Comment: ??? Read the docs on [`Serial.available()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Available). 0 means there is no data inside serial buffer to be read. I don't know from where you got array indices.

Comment: I ran you code and it has the problems I mentioned with the delay and multiple commands. And the `if(Serial.available() == 0)` is pretty much useless there, since it's always evaluated to `true` because you just emptied the buffer with `Serial.readString()`.

Comment: Also here is a link, how you should actually read from serial: [Reading Serial on the Arduino](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/)

Comment: Well as expected, your link is from "Majenko's Hardware Hacking Blog" Aka that "DIY guy playing with arduino", but as you usual, I think it's pointless to argue, keep on beliving it, if it works for you power to you. Good luck man!

Comment: As expected, you don't know what you are talking about. Majenko is the user with the most rep on [Arduino Stack Exchange](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/4143/majenko).

Comment: Ok cool thank you, good luck to you. To user that asked this question: please see what fits you best. Thx